# Can I create a mutator for a table field that doesn't exist?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, setter, eloquent

### Question

In Laravel 4, say I have 2 models `Post` and `Comment` with a one-to-many relationship. I would like to be able to do...

```
Post::create(['post_title' => 'foo',
               'comment' => ['text' => 'Some comment']);
```

...and for this to create the post record *as well as* a new comment record. This is my attempt:-

### My Attempt

```
class Post extends Model {

  // Make all field mutable
  public static $unguarded = true;

  // Create relationship
  public function comments() {
      return $this->hasMany('Comment');
  }

  // Setter for comment
  public function setComment($comment) {
      $this->comments()->create($comment);
      return FALSE;
  }
}
```

### Error

But I get the error:-

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'comment' in 'field list'
```

Is it possible to get Laravel to not look for the field? I tried returning `FALSE` from the setter but that doesn't seem to work.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent tested - but this should work;

```
class Post extends Model {

  public function comments() {
      return $this->hasMany('Comment');
  }

  public function createPostAndComment($post, $comment)
  {
      if ($this->create($post))
      {
           $this->comments()->save($comment);
      }
  }
}
```

You can [read more here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models).